# I am unable to pair with a custom passcode using BluetoothAuthenticateDevice API in c++ windows

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, bluetooth, pairing

Goal:- I want to pair my system (with windows 10 OS) to a bluetooth device using a custom pin such as "1234". I do not want the default 6 byte random password comparison done by windows.

Things I have confirmed:-

1. The device supports both 6 byte random password comparison mode of pairing (also called SSP or simple safe pairing) as well as custom pincode pairing
2. I was able to successfully pair the device with windows using SSP mode using windows 10 GUI as well as BluetoothAuthenticateDevice in c++
3. There is no support from windows 10 GUI to initiate pairing with a custom password. So I even tried running the windows universal sample code example for 'Device Enumeration and Pairing' but couldn't get it to work with a custom code either.

Issues I am facing:-

I am using the BluetoothAuthenticateDevice API with a custom password but when I run the compiled code the windows just ignores it and pairs with 6 byte random password comparison. I have attached a part of my code below

```
                //custom code for authentication
                printf("Authenticating...");
                PWSTR pwString = L"1234";
                ULONG pwLen = wcslen(pwString);
                DWORD retVal = BluetoothAuthenticateDevice(NULL,NULL, &deviceInfo, pwString, pwLen);
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: First you have to disable AuthenticationAgent.Next yo uhave to disable SSP.

Comment: How do I disable AuthenticationAgent and SSP?

Comment: Look through SO, I already posted the code.

Comment: What is an SO? can you please be elaborate?

Comment: SO = StackOverflow

Comment: please share with me the link to your code

Comment: Since Stackoverflow does not allow to post code with copyrights here and I can not share any code without copyrights from our commercial product I can not put it here.

Comment: So the code to perform a simple pin pairing operation using bluetooth is copyrighted? I didn't know that. If you can't share the code you can surely share with me (if you know) any links to the sources where this issue is discussed and addressed.

Comment: *...when I run the compiled code the windows just ignores it and pairs with 6 byte random password comparison...* Yes, I can reproduce this issue. `BluetoothAuthenticateDevice` is set as deprecated in bluetoothapis.h. For application developed for new version Windows `BluetoothAuthenticateDeviceEx` is recommended.

Comment: The supported [authentication method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/ne-bluetoothapis-bluetooth_authentication_method) via a PIN, out-of-band data, numeric comparison, passkey notification and passkey.